# Getting the average value of each hour for specific columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame with the date/time passed as "parse_dates" and then set as the index column for the data frame.

```
                      Flow  Enter  Leave    kWE          kW
Time                                                       
2021-08-30 08:50:00  24.22   14.0    5.7  66.56  619.478012
2021-08-30 08:51:00  24.22   14.0    5.7  66.56  619.478012
```

I want to get the average values of columns 'kWE' and 'Flow' per hour and day though i'm unsure of how to extract the data when the date/time is set as the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with hourly (`h`) frequency:

```
cols = ['Flow', 'kWE']
df.resample('h')[cols].mean()
```

output:

```
                      Flow    kWE
Time                             
2021-08-30 08:00:00  24.22  66.56
```

Or using `origin='start'` to use the first value as starting point.

Note the different index. Here the result is the same but this might give a different output on larger data depending on how rows will cluster:

```
df.resample('h', origin='start')[cols].mean()
```

output:

```
                      Flow    kWE
Time                             
2021-08-30 08:50:00  24.22  66.56
```

Comment: Thank you for you're help :) when i put in either code, it comes up with the error 'Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: Use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` first

Comment: ahh thank you, that solved that error but now its saying 'day is out of range for month: 0'. Sorry for all the questions, im still v new to coding

Comment: Have you invalid dates? Try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 #Preparing data

string = """Time  Flow  Enter  Leave  kWE  kW
2021-08-30 08:50:00  24.22  14.0  5.7  66.56  619.478012
2021-08-30 08:51:00  24.22  14.0  5.7  66.56  619.478012"""

data = [x.split('  ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index('Time')

#Solution, daily and hourly averages:
df.groupby(df.index.day)[['kWE', 'Flow']].mean()
df.groupby(df.index.hour)[['kWE', 'Flow']].mean()
```